# Copy value from Lookup (CountRelated) column to another 'Number' column

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

I'm trying to visualise data using Google charts, but it won't work with Lookup (count related) columns, so I'm trying to convert those values to Numbers using workflow and that won't work either using my methods that I know.

My setup now:

SharePoint Online.

List 1: a list of 24 hours in a day.

- 'Title' column: 24 items, from 00 to 23.
- 'Count' lookup (count related) column counting how many times certain hour appears in List 2

List 2: a list of items and their time.

- 'Time' is a calculated column that takes values from 'Hours' and 'Minutes' lookup columns that are linked to List 1.
- 'Hours' has a choice of 00-23 hours from List 1, same as 'Minutes', but I only want to count 'hours' frequency at this moment.

I'm also trying to get workflow to do the calculations.

Are there any known ways to get this working?

Comment: What is your setup? What are the columns in play, what is the cast of the calculated column? What SharePoint version are you using? Needs more info here...

Comment: @Mike hey, I updated the post with extra info.

Comment: If an answer was helpful could you remove your question from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Calculated Columns can not reference Lookup Columns,

since you are adding JavaScript for Google Charts anyway
CSR (Client Side Rendering) JavaScript is the best option.

Use the WYSIWYG [Cisar editor](https://365csi.nl/cisar)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I'm just not sure about how to put CSR and Google chart codes together and link their variables.

Comment: That is where you have to learn and apply Microsofts CSR technology (with Cisar!)

Comment: Where can I learn CSR and how to obtain values from certain fields as I'm struggling to understand it. So many websites with different approaches and none of them worked for me so far.. Most of guides cover formatting, which I already know how to use, but how to use that data with other scripts.. Where's the CSR and CTX documentation?

Comment: start with https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views, then google/stackoverflow your way through.  This will take time, just like when learning to drive a car..